# OutputStreams in Java

Tags: java, swing, file-io, outputstream

I was looking through the documentation for [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html), and I haven't seen any methods for moving the "write pointer" to a specified spot (although I have seen a constructor for **completely** rewriting ALL data in the file, and I have seen a constructor for simply appending the writtenData to the end of the file. Are there any OutputStreams that I could use that allow me to write **anywhere**?

Also, I have been having trouble with the ObjectInputStream. I wrote some test code to test Object updating (what I really plan on doing is writing an array of two `JTable`s to a file, and updating that array when I receive two `JTable`s from a client). I have tried writing a `String` to a text file (I don't think file extension matters to Java, but I could be wrong), and for some reason, it seems that the `ObjectInputStream` that I was using is erasing all the contents of the file! Does anyone know what might be causing this to happen? (It seems to happen even when the only thing my program is doing is reading the Strings via the ObjectInputStream.)

Comment: Take a look at [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Comment: I am afraid that, since this is happening, if I try using the ObjectInputStream to read the Objects "for real", it might break Object serialization!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was looking through the documentation for FileOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream, and I haven't seen any methods for moving the "write pointer" to a specified spot

Take a look at [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

> what I really plan on doing is writing an array of two JTables to a file

`JTable` has some fields that are declared as `transient`, where `transient` objects cannot be serialized (their references will be `null` after deserialization).

Comment: Yeah, all the editing stuff and renderers, which I won't be needing!

Comment: The cells in the JTables being sent are not editable, and they are strictly used for collection of data (from a math game).

Answer (score 0):

The answer above this one answered my first question, but as for the file itself resetting, it was because I tried initializing EVERYTHING in the constructor (including the `OutputStream`s). The initialization of the `FileOutputStream` caused whatever data was in the file to be erased.